# Struggling with proof, by contrapositive?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

[image]

I am having trouble solving this proof. I tried to do a proof by contrapositive.

Q = $(u+z)/(v+w) < z/w$

P = $(u/v < x/y \land x/y < z/w)$

Assuming $\lnot Q$ got me:  $u/v \ge z/w$

If $\lnot P$ is $ (u/v \ge x/y \lor x/y \ge z/w)$

Does this mean that $\lnot Q  \implies \lnot P$, Because  $(u/v \ge z/w)$ would make   $\lnot P$ True depending on the value of $x/y$ ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the implication follows: consider any $x/y$. If it is greater than $u/v$, then it is $> u/v \ge z/w$, so that $\lnot P$ holds, while if it is $\le u/v$, then again $\lnot P$ holds.